# Change background image css property every 5sec in react

Tags: reactjs

I have array of images that I am getting from the server. I want to change the background image every 5seconds. How I can achieve this in react?

```
    const HomeBanner = (props) => {
   
      const [x, setX] = useState(1);
    
      function changeImage(x,images) {
        setX(x+1)        
        if(x >= images.length) {
            setX(0)
        } 
        setTimeout(changeImage(x,images), 3000);
      }
      
    useEffect(() => {
  changeImage(x,props.settings.banners) 
});

      return (
        <div className="hero-section background-is-dark" id="homepage-banner" style={{backgroundImage: "url(" + props.settings.banners[x].banner + ")"}}>
    
        </div>
      );
    };
```

When I use above code i am getting this error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: You are calling `setTimeout(changeImage(...), 3000)` within `changeImage`, resulting in an infinite recursion. You want to `setTimeout` **outside** the definition of `changeImage`

Comment: But I need to change the image till the user is on the homepage @cSharp how to achieve this

Comment: See if [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) solves your problem.